# Validate request using GRPC server interceptor

Tags: java, grpc

I need to validate and log some of the data of grpc service request using an interceptor. I checked interceptCall of ServerInterceptor and could not find a way to get the request object. Is there any way to get the request object inside an interceptor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return and extend a `ForwardingServerCallListener` and listen to the `ServerCall.Listener.onMessage()` callback.

Comment: Cool, thanks. So, when validation passes I call `super.onMessage(message)` inside my `onMessage()` implementation. And on error I can `call#close(Status)`?

Comment: Yes, you can use call.close(), but since call is not thread-safe you can only use it if you have not passed call down the interceptor chain. So for a unary call you can just delay propagating the headers until the first message. For streaming it gets more complicated.

Comment: Thank you Eric. If I call `next.startCall(call, headers);` to get my `ForwardingServerCallListener` delegate, have I passed the call down the interceptor chain? Judging from the docs, I don't think so... I'm assuming "passing down the interceptor chain" mean using `super.onMessage()`. I am using the direct executor so it shouldn't matter?

Comment: Yes, calling startCall is passing the call down the chain. Basically, the application will receive the call and then can start calling methods on it. onMessage is used in the Listener, which is in the opposite direction. "up" vs "down" is a bit ambiguous; what's important is whether the next interceptor in the chain (or the application) received the call.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still confused though, how can I delay propagating the headers until the first message?

Comment: You get to delay things manually. You could save the headers in a field, for example.

Comment: Can you provide a github link? It's easier to understand if there is a complete example? Thank you