# Approach to validate request in ServerInterceptor using java grpc

Tags: java, validation, grpc, interceptor, grpc-java

I am using GRPC Java and want to validate the request using interceptors.

Many links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089459/how-can-i-get-annotations-on-rpc-method-being-called-in-grpc-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389771/validate-request-using-grpc-server-interceptor) tells an approach to use [onMessage()](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerCall.Listener.html#onMessage-ReqT-) to access request, but i want to know what further they are doing to validate the request.

Also, the message parameter in onMessage() is generic, i can't directly access request field parameters but have to typecast the message using some if-else/switch-case and then apply checks on each field individually, which is the last option for me right now.

Say for example, here is a sample proto file:

```
...
service XYZService {
  rpc abc(Request1) returns (Response1);
  rpc def(Request2) returns (Response2);
  .
  .
  .
}

message Request1 {
  string name = 1;
  int32 number = 2;
}

message Request2 {
  string name = 1;
  int32 number = 2;
  string email = 3;
}
...
```

Also i simply print the message parameter of onMessage() and found that request parameters as raw string(message.toString()), but those parameters are not shown in string when sending default values(like "" for string or 0 for int32) [I am using bloomrpc to send the requests on local machine]. So those value will not be shown in raw string when sending default value or there is something in bloomrpc?

So my 2 questions are:

1. Different approaches to validate requests(considering many requests have some common fields whose check conditions will also be same).
2. Any workaround to show default value parameters in raw string.

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf doesn't send default values on wire. To have consistence behavior, it doesn't print(toString) default values. IMO, if it prints the defaults, it can be annoying especially if you have many many fields.

I don't think you need to worry about the toString behavior when validating the object. because, when you use getter, it should return the default value (e.g. "" for string field).

Answer (score 0):

[LogNet's gRPC Spring boot starter](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter)  natively supports integration with Spring Boot Validation, you can read more how to configure constraints using Java Beans validation XML configuration support [here](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter#implementing-message-validation)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this starter